# Non interactive expo local build

Tags: react-native, expo, fastlane

I am experiencing for the first time the world of expo. So far I like the tool a lot, but I want to use it with my own cloud instead of the default one.
In practice, I want to setup my own distribution pipeline.

I already have experience with react-native and fastlane, but I'm curious to see if expo offers something better.

I already tested locally `eas build --local` and it works great but on the expo documentation I'm unable to find how to properly use the `non-interactive` flag.

I want to configure in advance all the requirements, like keystore path on android or team id for apple. Were can I find all the environment variables to define?

The second part for me is understanding if the deploy can also be done locally, without accessing the expo servers.
I believe it's using fastlane under the hood so maybe there is a possibility.

Thanks